# PHP Adding an array element to each element in another array

Tags: php, arrays

Is  there a way to add elements from one array to each of the elements in another array ?

*For example*:

```
$color = array("black", "white", "yellow");

$number = array("1", "2", "3");
```

I want a new array to combine them all so it's :

```
$colornumber = array("1black", "1white", "1yellow", "2black", "2white", "2yellow" etc.)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Javascript version: [How to combine two arrays as a cartesian product?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34826075/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$colornumber = array();
foreach ($numbers as $number){
     foreach($colors as $color){
         $colornumber[] = $number.$color;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$colors = array("black", "white", "yellow");
$numbers = array("1", "2", "3");
$colors_numbers = array();

foreach ($numbers as $number):
   foreach ($colors as $color) {
    $colors_numbers[] = $number . $color;
   }
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$color = array("black", "white", "yellow");

$number = array("1", "2", "3");

function mergeArr($arr1,$arr2){

    if(is_array($arr1)&& is_array($arr2)){
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $val1){
    foreach($arr2 as $val2){
    $newArr[] = $val2.$val1;

    }
}
return $newArr;
}else{
return false;
}

}

print_r(mergeArr($color ,$number));
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [0] => 1black [1] => 2black [2] => 3black [3] => 1white [4] => 2white [5] => 3white [6] => 1yellow [7] => 2yellow [8] => 3yellow )
```