# Javascript check array for data derived from other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a small snippet of code that I am trying to figure out. I have three arrays, one is for `users`, the other is for `tools`.

The last array holds objects that have properties which are a combination of each user & tool.

**Example:**

```
var users = ['bob123', 'tim890'],
    tools = ['admin', 'videos'],
    tasks = [];
```

In the above code, there would be a total of four tasks. `bob123/admin`, `bob123/videos`, `tim890/admin`, `tim890/videos`.

I am trying to figure out how to check in the array of objects (`tasks`) to see if a user/tool combination exists. If not, it runs it through a create function.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
var users = ['bob123', 'tim890'],
  tools = ['admin', 'videos'],
  tasks = [];


// Check to see if tasks have been created for each tool/user combo
function checkTasks() {
  /* 
    Loop over all the tasks.
    If a task doesnt exist for a specific
    tool/user combo, create it.
   */

   // Pseudo Code
   Loop Begin
     if bob123 admin does not exist in tasks {
        createTask('bob123', 'admin');
     }
   Loop End
}

// Create a new task if one doesn't exist
function createTask(user, tool) {

    // Create a new task
    tasks.push({
      TaskUser: user,
      TaskTool: tool
    });

}

// Run our app
checkTasks();
```

Whats the best approach for this to check combinations of data between two arrays that exist in an object of a third array?

Comment: Why check? Just overrdide the whole array with a [**cartesian product**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826075/how-to-combine-two-arrays-as-a-cartesian-product) of the first two array.

Comment: `checkTasks()` will get run on the addition / removal of any `user` or `tool`. Once a task is created, there is other functionality on the page that will be exposed and the data will be stored with task object. For exampe, once a task is created, the user will be able to add a taskDuration on the UI. That value is then stored as a property on the `task`. If I overwrite it each time, I think I would lose that data? If its only run on add/removal of users/tools, it shouldn't impact anything that already has a combination created for it, leaving the new data in tact.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this kind of thing.
Here is an example:

```
var exists = tasks.some(task => task.TaskUser == user && task.TaskTool == tool);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a nested loop for that.

```
var users = ['bob123', 'tim890'],
    tools = ['admin', 'videos'],
    tasks = [];


// Check to see if tasks have been created for each tool/user combo
function checkTasks() {
    /* 
      Loop over all the tasks.
      If a task doesnt exist for a specific
      tool/user combo, create it.
     */

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        for (var u = 0; u < tools.length; u++) {
            if (!taskExists(users[i], tools[u]))
                createTask(users[i], tools[u])
        }
    }
}

// Check if a task with the specified user&tool exists
function taskExists(user, tool) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        if (tasks[i].TaskUser == user && tasks[i].TaskTool == tool)
            return true
    }
    return false
}

// Create a new task if one doesn't exist
function createTask(user, tool) {

    // Create a new task
    tasks.push({
        TaskUser: user,
        TaskTool: tool
    });

}

// Run our app
checkTasks();
```

Comment: I ran the code and it works. someone care to explain whats wrong with it?